# How to fetch a string out of "08-1_2-4_1517614" ie "1517614"

Tags: java, java-8

If i have string like 08-1_2-4_1517614 and if i need to fetch the value "1517614" out of this for string manipulation in java
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: the most easy way would be to `split("_")` and take the last one I guess; unless you know regex

Comment: `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_")+1,str.length())`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. it worked.

Comment: btw, you don't put [solved], you actually [accept an answer that you found appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex replace option:

```
String input = "08-1_2-4_1517614";
String output = input.replaceAll("^.*_", "");
```

A more general regex replace option using a capture group:

```
String output = input.replaceAll(".*(?<!\\d)(\\d+)$", "$1");
```

Or we could take a substring:

```
String output = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = " 08-1_2-4_1517614";
String [] tokens = test.split("_");
System.out.println(tokens[tokens.length - 1]);
```

Or with regex:

```
String test = " 08-1_2-4_1517614";
System.out.println(test.replaceFirst(".+_", ""));
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf("_") + 1));
```

Comment: Or `Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.+)_(.*)").matcher(test);
        System.out.println(matcher.find() ? matcher.group(2) : "");`

Answer (score 0):

Or use

```
 str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, str.length())
```

Comment: you don't need the last parameter though

Answer (score 0):

Is the pattern always the same?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int- could be your friend.

"08-1_2-4_1517614".substring(9, "08-1_2-4_1517614".length()) e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it, in case you want to resuse other parts of the original String.

```
  String num =  "08-1_2-4_1517614";
  String[] parts = num.split("_");
  String value = parts[parts.length - 1];
  System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple is to use regex to find all the numbers after the final underscore.

```
    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("[^_]+$");
    Matcher matcher = patt.matcher("08-1_2-4_1517614");
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }else{
        System.out.println("No Match Found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the one-liner:

```
System.out.println(myString.substring(9, 16));
```